# selecting element with dynamically set data-x attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a `video` tag which i use for a p2p chat the tag looks like this

```
<div id="secondary-user">
     <video id="their-video" data-peer="0" autoplay loop autobuffer muted playsinline controls></video>
</div>
```

i set data-peer chat dynamically when chat start with remote user specific id (peer)

```
function start_chat( remote_user_id , stream){

            $('#their-video').data('peer' , remote_user_id );    
           // add stream
}
```

i want to stop the stream of that specific video tag

```
function stop_chat( remote_user_id ){

      let player = $(`#their-video[data-peer="${remote_user_id }"]`) ; 
      //stop the stream 
}
```

the problem is selector cant find the element even tho i can see the data-peer is set correctly

[image]

the reason i dont want to use only id as selector is sometimes the stream get replaced with new one before i can call `stop_chat` and i dont want to stop the new stream ... so it's important to use data-peer on the selector

here is the output for

```
console.log(player.length);
console.log(player);
```

[image]

like @Toufiq Ahmed said using `attr` to set the value solved the problem ... i wonder why ?!

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us a console.log of `player` after the value has been assigned to that variable?

Comment: @devlincarnate you mean `console.log(player ); ` in the `stop_chat` function ?

Comment: I tried to recreate this $('#their-video').data('peer' , remote_user_id );  and found that data function doesn't create attribute in element. use jquery attr function insteatd.
for setting $('#elemnt').attr('data-peer', 'value') and for getting use $('#elemnt').attr('data-peer')

Comment: yes, in the `stop_chat` function.  And also, can you verify the value of  `${remote_user_id }`

Comment: @devlincarnate i've added the output to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate this $('#their-video').data('peer' , remote_user_id );  and found that data function doesn't create attribute in element. use jquery attr function insteatd.
for setting $('#elemnt').attr('data-peer', 'value') and for getting use $('#elemnt').attr('data-peer')

this way your $(`#their-video[data-peer="${remote_user_id }"]`) ; work just fine.